# NEO4J : ERROR: Unable to find java. (Cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neo4j, jvm

I am running into problems with Neo4J server under UBUNTU 16.04.
I wanted to install the version 2.3.3 of neo4j. Now when I tried to start the server, I got this error:

➜  ~ sudo /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start

ERROR: Unable to find java. (Cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java)
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 or OpenJDK(TM) to run Neo4j Server.
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.

The thing is that my JAVA_HOME is not the path given by the error:

➜  ~ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/

Any idea about the root cause of this issue?

Comment: what happens when you execute `java -version` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run it as 'sudo' you are running it as the root user, not your user. As a result your `JAVA_HOME` path (which is your user environment) won't apply.

Comment: You are right, I had a JAVA_HOME defined in the /etc/environment file. I removed it from there and now it works. Thanks